# What's the word for when someone produces a piece of art solely for the profit of it? Or art without any kind of artistic merit?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning

I know there's a word for this that I just can't remember

Comment: Are you looking for *mercinary*? It is. It is not about art specifically.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Damila "Mercenary" is good but the OP could say "purely commercial" to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

A noun for artistic work done purely for money is **hackwork** and the person responsible is a **hack**. *Hack* can also be used as an adjective to describe such work or the person who creates it.

Definitions of "hack" in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hack) include "a writer who works on order" and "a person who works solely for mercenary reasons". This seems to derive from an older meaning of a horse who was available for hire. Hack as an adjective can mean "working for hire especially with mediocre professional standards", "performed by or suited to a person who works or writes purely for the purpose of earning money : characteristic of a hack", "hackneyed, trite".

An example where it is used as an adjective is:

> the abrupt revelation of an enemy masquerading as a friend is such a hack plot twist

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hackwork) defines hackwork as "literary, artistic, or professional work done on order usually according to formula and in conformity with commercial standards". Its example sentences include:

> His oeuvre is full of hackwork: The pulps commonly paid by the word and Howard was happy to deliver words in bulk, allowing quantity to overwhelm quality.

> And so, at least for the moment, there has been some respite on the bestseller lists from the usual insider politics hackwork.

Answer (score -2):

There is a phrase  Ars Gratia Artis, meaning [art for he sake of art.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Art_for_art%27s_sake)  It is the motto of MGM although they didn't invent it.

[image]

A fairly obvious inversion of this is  *Ars gratia pecuniae*,  translation *Art for the sake of money.*

Many people have come up with this phrase.

Comment: Any justification for the assertion that many have come up with such a phrase? A contrived latinism is hardly English usage.

Comment: A google search returns a quarter million hits with numerous different people having thought of it independently. Examples: 1) https://davidperlstein.com/ars-gratia-pecuniae/  2) http://content.time.com/time/subscriber/article/0,33009,911883,00.html  3) http://www.classicmoviehub.com/facts-and-trivia/star/stan-freberg/page/1/

Comment: Thanks. An insight into a world unknown to me